# Parse all items with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to parse DOM with Simple HTML DOM Parser in PHP. Parsed content are movies, so I want to get every genre there is, but when i run my code I only get the last genre, not all. My code looks like this:

```
if ($obj) {
    foreach($obj as $key => $data) {
        $item['url'] = 'http://geo.saitebi.ge/movie/' . $page;
        $item['poster'] = 'http://geo.saitebi.ge/web/ka/img/movies/' . $page . '/240x340/' . $page . '.jpg';
        $item['geotitle'] = $data->find('div.movie-item-title', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['englishtitle'] = $data->find('div.movie-item-title-en', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['year'] = $data->find('div.movie-item-year', 0)->plaintext;
        foreach($data->find('a.movie-genre-item') as $genre) {
            $item['genres'] = $genre->plaintext . ', ';
        }
        $item['description'] = $data->find('div.movie-desctiption-more', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['imdb_rating'] = $data->find('a.imdb_vote', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['imdb_id'] = trim(substr($data->find('a.imdb_vote',0)->href, strrpos($data->find('a.imdb_vote',0)->href, '/') + 1));
    }
}
```

As you see I'm getting content as array. Then inside it I run another foreach loop to get all genre items but it only gets last genre item. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just overwriting the last set of data each time.  You need to set it to blank and then append it using `.=` each time, like...

```
$item['genres'] = '';
foreach($data->find('a.movie-genre-item') as $genre) {
   $item['genres'] .= $genre->plaintext . ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code are saving the same '$genre->plaintext' in $item with key 'genres'
so the same key replace the values every loop.

```
 foreach($data->find('a.movie-genre-item') as $genre) {
            $item['genres'] = $genre->plaintext . ', ';
 }
```

May $item['genres] can be an associative array.. i mean:

```
foreach($data->find('a.movie-genre-item') as $genre) {
             if ( !isset($item[$genre]) ) {
                      $item[$genre] = array();
              }
          array_push($item[$genre],$genre->plaintext);
     }
```

Comment: No need to do this. I was just overwriting the last set of data each time, so I needed to set it to blank and then append it using .= each time. Above answer solved the problem :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is genre code which you have to update

```
    // Here is you genre code 
    $movie_genre='';
    foreach($data->find('a.movie-genre-item') as $genre) {
        $movie_genre .= $genre->plaintext . ',';
    }

    // Here you can use rtrim for removing last comma from genre
    $item['genres'] = rtrim($movie_genre,',');
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for providing fix for removing last comma from genre. Thank you!